# RESTRICT ACCESS TO Controller ACTIONS For a list of users in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I  have a MVC4 Application that uses a custom authorize attribute, allowing users in certain  roles access to the application. This authorize attribute is on the controller, which means authorized users will have access to all actions within that controller.

However,some  of the authorized users only require access to one action only within  that controller.

What I really want is an action filter that would list users who shouldn't have access to certain actions.

What would be the appropriate way to approach this in terms of best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you want like this

```
[Authorize(Roles = "HrAdmin, CanEnterPayroll")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EnterPayroll(string id)
{
    //  . . . Enter some payroll . . . 
}


[Authorize(Roles = "HrAdmin, CanEditPayroll, CanProcessPayroll")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditPayroll(string id)
{
    //  . . . Edit existing payroll entries . . . 
}

[Authorize(Roles = "HrAdmin, CanProcessPayroll")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProcessPayroll(string id)
{
    //  . . . Process payroll and cut checks . . . 
}
```

for roles and permission you can refer this link.
[Implementing Group-Based Permissions Management](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/730841/ASP-NET-MVC-Identity-Implementing-Group-Based)